# IBM MobileFirst -- get location

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have MobileFirst (V7.O) app . How do I get the current latitude/Longitude for the device. Basically, I am recording some information at various point in my app and user can be moving.. So, at various instance, I would like to get the current lat/log..

Can you please provide some hints and how to get this information

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova is bundled in your MobileFirst project. As such you can take use of Cordova APIs to achieve this.

See the following (scroll down to the API usage): https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

```
// onSuccess Callback
// This method accepts a Position object, which contains the
// current GPS coordinates
//
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
          'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
          'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
          'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
};

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```